# No password protection for drop box on my home computer. Once windows opens everything is available

Tags: security, dropbox

We have an office in the home tax business using a shared NAS server. How can I protect my dropbox files from non family members if they are using our pc? example a temporary seasonal employee.

Comment: You'll need to provide way more info about the computer(s) in question to get a decent answer.  E.g.: Which OS (version and edition) is the PC using?  Why not simply have the temporary worker log in as a different user, and deny that user access to your DropBox folder?

Comment: Set up a non business PC for guests and do not attach it to the server.. Why would you risk your business PC's to this type of situation. There are some things you just don't share, especially when a business depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a piece of folder locker software to lock it with a password.

You can also do this with windows:
1. Right click on the folder.
2. Click properties
3. Click on the general tab
4. Go to attributes and hit Hidden.
5. Apply
6. Select Apply these changes to folder, subfolders and files
7. Click done.

To find it once it is hidden, do the following:
1. Go to start menu and type "folder options" (on Windows 10 this will be displayed as File Explorer options)
2. Go to View tab
3. Under 'Hidden Files and Folders' select 'Show hidden files, folders, and drives.'